# Function specific settings in Azure Function app

Tags: azure, settings, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I plan to use Timer functions to monitor my deployed environments. I have 5 environments for now and was planning to create 5 different functions in the same function app. I need to specify the URLs for each monitor to see which environment to monitor. How can I do that per function specific.

Or if there is any other approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the proxy feature. Look at the docs for [Working with Azure Functions Proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies/?WT.mc_id=teams-stackoverflow-shboyer)

Comment: How do I make them time trigger? I need a continuous monitoring

Comment: The function itself must be a timer function. But if you are looking for monitoring, you should look at Azure Monitor and/or Azure Application Insights. These services are better served for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Create a single timer function and maintain a url list in Azure Table Storage (key,value). Read the urls from table storage and aggregate all the results in your function.